# How to vertically center multiple images of varying heights in a row using vertical-align: middle

Tags: image, containers, vertical-alignment

There are many questions on this topic already posted so sorry for posting another. However, none of the others that refer to my situation -- vertically aligning a row of images of undefined height, rather than a single image -- have received a reply that accomplishes what I need to do. As far as I can tell, Kizu's first solution here: [How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-properly-align-an-image-vertically) should be the thing, but alas I can't get it to work.

So, I have a container div. I can specify a height for this div if necessary. I can also place this div in another div if necessary.

Inside the div, I want to place a row of images of varying heights. These images should be vertically centered *in relation to each other* (not just in relation to the container div).

I cannot use background images in this case (the images are being placed within a text widget for easy replacement purposes). 
As far as I can tell, I also cannot use display: table on the container div and display: table cell on my images, because the table cell must have a defined height, and my images are of varying heights.

Here is my code -- I've got a couple of extra divs (#footer-single-widget and .footer-single) to achieve the overall centering and padding I want, so I'm including these as well in case one of them is affecting the subsequent divs:

```
<div id="footer-single-widget">
        <div class="footer-single">

       <div class="textwidget">
       <div class="media">

<img src="#image-1" width="103" height="36" class="alignleft" />
<img src="#image-1" width="103" height="40" class="alignleft" />
<img src="#image-1" width="103" height="26" class="alignleft" />
<img src="#image-1" width="103" height="40" class="alignleft" />

       </div><!-- end of .textwidget -->
       </div><!-- end of .media -->

        </div><!-- end of .footer-single -->
    </div><!-- end of #footer-single-widget -->
```

And the CSS:

```
#footer-single-widget {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-single {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer-single-widget .textwidget {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 980px;
}

.media {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.media img.alignleft {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 40px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

The frustrating thing is at some point I achieved exactly this effect -- then decided I didn't need it (all my images at that point were the same height) and deleted the code I had written. Now I need it again and don't have the faintest memory of what I did! But I know it's possible... somehow. Thanks for your advice.